# How to declare knockout component in typescript?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, typescript

I am trying to follow example to create a component in knockout.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html

But I have to write a code in typescript. So how can I register component in knockout using typescript?

What should I write in .ts file to convert it in something-like below.

```
ko.components.register('like-widget', {
viewModel: function(params) {
```

I started to write code in constructor but don't know how to complete it.

```
class TodayViewModel {
todayWidget: KnockoutComponents;
config: KnockoutComponentTypes.Config;
constructor() {
    this.config.template = "sdfs.html";
    this.todayWidget.register("like-widget", this.config);
}}export = TodayViewModel;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use this approach:

```
// import knockout
import ko = require("knockout");

// your viewmodel class
class TodayViewModel {
    todayText = ko.observable<string>();
}


// register the component
ko.components.register("like-widget", {
    viewModel: TodayViewModel,
    template: "<span data-bind='text: todayText'></span>"
});
```

P.S. you will need [knockout.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped](https://www.nuget.org/packages/knockout.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/)